# Class or Enum structure for control types and codes

Tags: c#, enums, derived-class

I would like to implement a class with control codes for the peers of my socket communication. I tried it with enums and derived classes but my tries doesn't work.

I would like to have a `Type` which contains different `Codes`. For example *Control* as type with *Wakeup* and *Shutdown* as code information's.

The peer should be able to use a Switch Case to identify the information. Something like:

```
switch(data.Type)
{
    case Control:
        /* Check diffrent codes */
    break;
    case Notification:
        /* Check diffrent codes */
    break;
}
```

I tried it with following, but sadly I cannot use Switch Case or similar to identify the information.

```
public abstract class Type
{
    private readonly String _code;

    protected Type(String code)
    {
        _code = code;
    }

    public String Code
    {
        get { return _code; }
    }
}

public sealed class Control : Type
{
    public static readonly Control Wakeup = new Control("Wakeup");
    public static readonly Control Shutdown = new Control("Shutdown");

    private Control(String code) : base(code)
    {
    }
}
```

Any Idea how to implement this? Please consider, that *TypeXXX* should not combinable with *CodeYYYY*. Thanks for your advices!

**Edit**

I have a TCP Client and Server Socket. The general communication works fine. Now I would like to implement a class or something similar that tells the peer which kind of information he received. That he is able to decide what he should he do with the information. I thought something like the [ICMP Control Messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Control_messages) would be nice. I have a general Type of Information and the Code specify it.

The type code relationship looks like this:

```
+--------------+-------------+
|     Type     |    Code     |
+--------------+-------------+
| Control      | Shutdown    |
|              | Wakeup      |
|              | CheckUpdate |
|              | ForceUpdate |
| -----------  | ----------- |
| Notification | Online      |
|              | Offline     |
|              | Login       |
|              | Logoff      |
| -----------  | ----------- |
| Data         | Zip         |
+--------------+-------------+
```

The package looks like this:

```
+------+------+---------+
| Type | Code | Payload |
+------+------+---------+
```

The receiver checks the `Type` and `Code` and after that start to process the payload.

Comment: is there a reason you don't want another level of inheritance?

Comment: @Sayse Where do you mean? I guss it's ok. Any advice?

Comment: Azhar has given a pretty good example. Otherwise you'd have to go through a switch statement any time you wished to do anything with your control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two classes that inherits from Control class:

```
public class WakeUp : Control
{
}

public class ShutDown : Control
{
}
```

Then use this method to create a new instance of the specific control:

```
public T CreateControl<T>() where T : Control, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Use the above method as:

```
var wakeupControl = CreateControl<WakeUp>();
var shutdownControl = CreateControl<ShutDown>();
```

**UPDATE:**

Have a look at the strategy pattern http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I assume that Control still in inherits from Type, right? How do I check the Type?

Comment: So did you create "data.Type" or is this something you have to use?

Comment: I created it. It's a object that contain the `Type` and the `Payload`. Maybe I was unexact. There are more then just one `Type`. There is Control, Notification, Data, ... all these types has own codes. It should be a little bit like the [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Control_messages) implementation. Every type has his codes. Greetz.

Comment: Can you give me a list of what codes goes into Control and what codes go into Notification (just examples) and then what do you intend to do with those codes?

Comment: Please see me **Edit**. Does this help?

Comment: One thing I don't understand is whether these types and codes are just there to do conditional checks and depending upon which ones are selected you execute a payload? OR they are actually classes that means something? If they are simple strings/enums to do checks then it's very simple to implement.

Comment: With the combination Type/Code, the receiver should recognize what he has to do with the payload. I look for a nice way, to tell the receiver what kind of data he received. I thought something like nested enums would be nice, but this is not possible and I have no idea how to do it in a good way with inheritance. Maybe their is a other much better way. I guess I think to complicated :). Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

From C# language reference (8.7.2). switch (switch expression) { case... }

If the type of the switch expression is *sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, string, or an enum-type*, then that is the governing type of the switch statement. Otherwise, exactly one user-defined implicit conversion (Section 6.4) must exist from the type of the switch expression to one of the following possible governing types: *sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, string*. If no such implicit conversion exists, or if more than one such implicit conversion exists, a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are overcomplicating. This is how I would do it.

```
public enum Code { Wakeup, ShutDown, Notification1, Notification2 };
public enum Type { Control, Notification, Invalid }

public static class CodeCheck
{
    public static bool IsControl( Code code )
    {
        return code == Code.Wakeup || code == Code.ShutDown;
    }

    public static bool IsNotification( Code code )
    {
        return code == Code.Notification1 || code == Code.Notification2;
    }

    public static Type GetType( Code code )
    {
        if ( IsControl( code ) )
            return Type.Control;

        if ( IsNotification( code ) )
            return Type.Notification;

        return Type.Invalid;
    }
}
```

So user would do something like:

```
    public void ProcessCode( Code code )
    {
        switch ( CodeCheck.GetType( code ) )
        {
            case Type.Control:
                // do something
                break;

            case Type.Notification:
                // do something
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of how you can do it. This is after your edit so it covers all combinations:

```
public enum CodeValue { Wakeup, ShutDown, CheckUpdate, ForceUpdate, Online, Offline, Login, Logoff, Zip };
public enum TypeValue { Control, Notification, Data, Invalid }

public class Code
{
    public CodeValue CodeValue
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public TypeValue TypeValue
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Code( CodeValue code )
    {
        CodeValue = code;
        DetermineType();
        if ( TypeValue == TypeValue.Invalid )
            throw new ArgumentException( "code" );
    }


    private bool IsControl()
    {
        return CodeValue == CodeValue.Wakeup || CodeValue == CodeValue.ShutDown || CodeValue == CodeValue.CheckUpdate || CodeValue == CodeValue.ForceUpdate;
    }

    private bool IsNotification()
    {
        return CodeValue == CodeValue.Online || CodeValue == CodeValue.Offline || CodeValue == CodeValue.Login || CodeValue == CodeValue.Logoff;
    }

    private bool IsData()
    {
        return CodeValue == CodeValue.Zip;
    }

    private void DetermineType()
    {
        if ( IsControl() )
            TypeValue = TypeValue.Control;

        if ( IsNotification() )
            TypeValue = TypeValue.Notification;

        if ( IsData() )
            TypeValue = TypeValue.Data;

        TypeValue = TypeValue.Invalid;
    }
}
```

User would use it like this:

```
    public void ProcessCode( Code code )
    {
        switch ( code.TypeValue )
        {
            case TypeValue.Control:
                // do something
                break;

            case TypeValue.Notification:
                // do something
                break;
        }
    }
```